# controllers are loaded after constants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have constant in UsersHelper:

```
CONSTANT_CONTROLLER =  [["Configuration", MerchantsController], ["System", SystemStatusController]]
```

But since I am using AuthenticatedSystem the server failes with:

```
undefined method `requires_role' for MerchantsController:Class
```

I tried to include AuthenticatedSystem but it didn't worked. When I have method:

```
def controller_display_name_to_real_name
    [["Configuration", MerchantsController], ["System", SystemStatusController]]
end
```

everything is OK. I guess that constants are early loaded when controllers are not loaded. Is this right?

Comment: I think you're right. One of the solutions I found is to set only strings into constants (`'MerchantsController'` e.g.). Then, when I need to use it (i.e. when all the constants are loaded), I call `MY_CONSTANT.constantize`. But maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response sounds like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Try as following

```
Controller.constantize
```

You have to [constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) your controller name.